# How to get a specific field in schema.pre() method?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I using nodejs with mongoose and I want to get the user password before updating the document. I'm using `schema.pre()` method to be invoked before updating, but I don't know how to get the user password in this method.

here is my `UserSchema.pre()` method:

```
UserSchema.pre('update', function(next){
   var user = this;
   next();
});
```

and my schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true,
    unique: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 6
},
firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
},
lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 1,
    trim: true
},
tokens: [{
    access:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    token:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}]
});
```

Hope you can help me with this,
Thank you.

Comment: Whould you please add the definition of your Schema to the post?

Answer (score 0):

```
UserSchema.pre('update', function(next){
   var user = this;
   console.log(user._update); // contains the fields to be be updated
   next();
});
```

As you're updating single user, I'd suggest using pre `findOneAndUpdate` hook instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me,

```
UserSchema.pre('update', function(next){
   var user = this['_doc'];
   console.log(user); // contains the fields to be be updated
   next();
});
```